# How long does the Firebase local cache last in a browser?

Tags: firebase

I understand that data is cached locally and synced with a server, but it is unclear from the docs how long data is saved on the local machine.

If I quit my browser, do I need to re-download my data the next time I visit the app? Is the local data persisted permanently, syncing with the server-data like a git repository?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Firebase has offline disk persistence available for the iOS client, there is currently no offline storage out-of-the-box in the browser. If you quit your browser or navigate away from the page, only the user's authentication state / session is persisted while all application data will be re-synced.